# Continuous function with partial derivative that is continuous in one variable but not the other

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Does there exist a function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ with the following property

- $f$ is continuous
- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ exists
- For each fixed $y$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ is a continuous function of $x$
- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)$ is **not** a continuous function of $y$

I suspect the answer is yes, i.e. the first three properties do not imply the fourth since I don't see how to prove that, but I can't think of an easy example.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It does not exist. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **No, it doesn't exist.**

To show why, first some definitions:

> **DEFINITION: Continuous function.** Let $\Omega$ be a connected subset of $\Bbb R^n$. A function $ \boldsymbol F:\Omega\to\Bbb R^m$ is *continuous* at a point $\boldsymbol x$ if,
>
> - $\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x)$ exists
> - $\lim_{\boldsymbol x'\to \boldsymbol x}\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x')$ exists and is equal to $\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x)$.

> **DEFINITION: Derivative.** Let $U$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $\boldsymbol F: U\to\Bbb R^m$. The derivative of $F$ with respect to its $k$th argument at the point $\boldsymbol x$ is defined as
> $$(\partial_k \boldsymbol F)(\boldsymbol x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x+h~\boldsymbol e_k)-\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x)}{h}$$
> Where $\boldsymbol e_k$ is the unit vector in the $+x_k$ direction. If this limit exists at all points $\boldsymbol x\in U$, $F$ is said to be "*differentiable* on $U$".

---

**Problem:** Does there exist a function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ such that

- $f$ is continuous (in both arguments!)
- $\partial_1f$ exists everywhere in $\Bbb R^2$
- $\partial_1 f(\cdot ,x_2)$ **is** continuous
- $\exists x_1\in\Bbb R$ such that $\partial_1 f(x_1,\cdot)$ is **not** continuous

**ANSWER: No.**

*Proof:*

We know that $f$ is continuous, so it is continuous in both its first and second argument. This means that, for all $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$, $f(x,y)$ exists and $\lim_{y'\to y}f(x,y')$ exists. We *also* know that, since $\partial_x f$ exists, that $\forall (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$, $\partial_xf(x,y)$ exists which implies the limit
$$\partial_x f(x,y)=\lim_{x'\to x}\frac{f(x',y)-f(x,y)}{x'-x}\tag{*}$$
Exists.

So, we need to ask ourselves - is $\partial_x f$ continuous in its *second* argument? In other words, does $\lim_{y'\to y}(\partial_x f)(x,y')$ exist,  and is it equal to $(\partial_x f)(x,y)$ ? Well, from $(*)$, we should have
$$\lim_{y'\to y}(\partial_x f)(x,y')=\lim_{y'\to y}\lim_{x'\to x}\frac{f(x',y')-f(x,y')}{x'-x}\tag{**}$$
Let's park this for just a minute.

---

> **DEFINITION: Uniform convergence.** Let $\Omega$ be a connected subset of $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R$ and let $\boldsymbol F:\Omega\to\Bbb R^m$. We say that $\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x,t)\to \boldsymbol G(\boldsymbol x_0,t)$ as $\boldsymbol x\to \boldsymbol x_0$ *uniformly* if, for all $\epsilon\in\Bbb R_+$, there exists $\delta\in\Bbb R_+$ such that, for all $\boldsymbol x$,
> $$|\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol x_0|<\delta\implies |\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x,t)-\boldsymbol G(\boldsymbol x_0,t)|<\epsilon$$

It is proved [on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839213/show-the-uniform-convergence-of-the-partial-derivatives) that partial derivatives converge uniformly, i.e
$$\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}\to (\partial_x f)(x,y)~~~\text{as}~h\to 0 \\ \text{Uniformly.}$$

---

Coming back to the task at hand, we are going to need the [Moore-Osgood theorem](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/when-can-you-switch-limits-in-calculus-1cfd5e5d6c6a):

> If $\lim_{t'\to t}f(\boldsymbol x,t')\to h(\boldsymbol x)$ pointwise (i.e, the limit exists) and $\lim_{\boldsymbol x'\to \boldsymbol x}f(\boldsymbol x',t)\to g(t)$ uniformly, then
> $$\lim_{\boldsymbol x'\to \boldsymbol x}\lim_{t'\to t}f(\boldsymbol x',t')=\lim_{t'\to t}\lim_{\boldsymbol x'\to \boldsymbol x}f(\boldsymbol x',t')=\lim_{(\boldsymbol x',t')\to(\boldsymbol x,t)}f(\boldsymbol x',t')$$

Returning to $(**)$, from the uniform convergence of the partial derivative we know that
$$\frac{f(x',y)-f(x,y)}{x'-x}\to \partial_x f(x,y)~~~\text{as}~x'\to x \\ \text{Uniformly}$$
So due to the Moore-Osgood theorem this is already enough to move in the $y$ limit,
$$\lim_{y'\to y}\lim_{x'\to x}\frac{f(x',y')-f(x,y')}{x'-x}=\lim_{x'\to x}\lim_{y'\to y}\frac{f(x',y')-f(x,y')}{x'-x}$$
But, $f$ is continuous, and so the function
$$\frac{f(x',~\cdot ~)-f(x,~\cdot~)}{x'-x}$$
Is also certainly continuous, which means by definition that
$$\lim_{y'\to y}\frac{f(x',y')-f(x,y')}{x'-x}=\frac{f(x',y)-f(x,y)}{x'-x}$$
Hence
$$\lim_{y'\to y}(\partial_x f)(x,y')\\=\lim_{x'\to x}\lim_{y'\to y}\frac{f(x',y')-f(x,y')}{x'-x}=\lim_{x'\to x}\frac{f(x',y)-f(x,y)}{x'-x} \\ =(\partial_x f)(x,y)$$
From $(*)$. Hence we have shown
$$\lim_{y'\to y}(\partial_x f)(x,y')=(\partial_x f)(x,y)$$
Hence $\partial_x f$ is continuous in its second argument.

$\blacksquare$

---

The intuition behind this rather ugly proof is that the $\partial_x$ operator "only acts along the $x$ axis." So if $f$ was continuous in its second argument to begin with, taking limits on its first argument won't change that.

Comment: If you spot any mistakes (extra/missing primes, quantifiers in the wrong order, etc...) please let me know and I will correct it!

Comment: Side note - the continuity of $\partial_1 f$ is not even necessary for this to hold.

Comment: Wow, amazing answer!

Comment: @hideki Well, I decided to ask one of my old professors about this question and he was able to come up with the example
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x-2y\arctan(x/y) & y\neq 0 \\ x & y=0\end{cases}$$
Which has derivative
$$\partial_x f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} & y\neq 0 \\ 1 & y=0\end{cases}$$
Which is continuous in $x$ everywhere, but $(\partial_x f)(0,y)$ has a removable discontinuity at $y=0$. So my proof must be wrong. But I am not sure where.

Comment: Wow, but still, thanks for looking into this so deeply! This example checks out. In a way I'm glad there is an example since free regularity is very rare. I suspect where the proof goes wrong is the claim that partial derivatives converge uniformly. Looking more closely at the post and it's proof, it's an existence statement ($\exists \delta$) not a uniform statement.

Don't know if it's appropriate but I'm curious about who you asked! I've also asked around for an answer to the problem but to no avail. I'd love a name drop, but I'd respect it if they declined.

Comment: @hideki He declined to be named, but I can say that he has research interests in quantum information theory.